# Timer script does not loop (Roblox Lua)

Tags: lua, roblox

Timer script stops at 2:29 and won`t count down from there. It's supposed to count down to zero, but will stop after 1 loop. The while true do loop keeps going, but either the text label won't display it, or the minutes and seconds variables aren't changing. I need help making this work.

```
local starterGui = game:GetService("StarterGui")
local Guis = starterGui.RoundTimer --Includes the time textlabel.
local Seconds = 30
local Minutes = 2

repeat
    wait(1)
    if Seconds < 9 then
        if Seconds == 0 then
            Seconds = 59
            Minutes = Minutes - 1
        else
            Seconds = Seconds - 1
        end
        Guis.Time.Text = tostring(Minutes)..":0"..tostring(Seconds)
    else
        Seconds = Seconds - 1
        Guis.Time.Text = tostring(Minutes)..":"..tostring(Seconds)
    end
until Seconds < 1 and Minutes < 1
```

Comment: print the condition right before the end of the loop, something like `print(Seconds, Minutes,  Seconds < 1 and Minutes < 1)` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've known this for a bit now, but in case anyone wants to know what worked:

```lua
while true do
    wait(1)
    local timeleft = game.ReplicatedStorage.Seconds.Value -- the seconds value
    local minutes = math.floor(timeleft/60) -- getting the amount of minutes by dividing seconds by 60
    local seconds = timeleft%60 -- gets the remaining seconds by using modulo 60 with time left.

    script.Parent.Text = string.format("%d:%02d", minutes%60, seconds) -- formats this into a timer.
end
```

More information about `string.format()` can be found here: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Format-String

How %/modulo works:
Say you have 90 seconds and want to turn it into 1:30. You've already figured out that by using timeleft/60 you can figure out that there is one minute on the clock. Using `timeleft%60` divides time left by 60 and then returns the remainder, therefore giving you 30.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem with the overall logic, so no reason for it to stop at 2:29, but there are some problems with formatting, as this is what I get when I run the script (a fragment):

```
1:10
1:9
1:8
1:07
1:06
1:05
1:04
1:03
1:02
1:01
1:00
0:059
0:58
```

As you can see, :8, :9, and :059 are formatted incorrectly.

Something like this may work a bit better:

```
repeat
    Guis.Time.Text = ("%d:%02d"):format(Minutes, Seconds)
    wait(1)
    Seconds = Seconds - 1
    if Seconds < 0 then
      Minutes = Minutes - 1
      Seconds = 59
    end
until Seconds < 1 and Minutes < 1
```

Comment: Using this code still sadly does not fix the problem of the timer stopping early. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Same issue as @rml1310. Probably fixes the formatting issues but doesn't fix it stopping early.

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with code - may be place of execution is time limited?

Comment: As I said, I don't see a problem with the overall logic, so the issue is likely to be outside of the code that is shown. If you want to troubleshoot it further, I'd add `print` statements around the `wait(1)` call (just to be sure that the control is not blocked inside of it) and after the loop (to confirm that it's not exited prematurely).